# Xcode 6.1 not detecting device iPhone 5s running iOS 8.1

Tags: xcode6.1, ios8.1

My 5s was running fine with Xcode 6.0.1 when I was using iOS 8.0.2. But then I upgraded to iOS 8.1, build my code, and I got an error saying "Xcode cannot run using the selected device. No supported iOS devices are available. Mark an iOS device as 'Use for Development' to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination." So then I figure I need to upgrade to Xcode 6.1, but I still got the same error. The strange thing is under Windows > Devices I can see my iPhone 5s information. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not alone ;) Got the same thing

Comment: In my case I forgot to connect the lightning cable to mac. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've got the same problem. Just uncheck "Show in Run Destinations Menu" and check it again in Device Window for your device. It works for me.

Comment: Where can I found this option "Show in Run Destinations Menu"?

Comment: You should click right mouse button at your device in Window -> Devices

Comment: what if i could not see my device on the list? but i've could see it on the iTunes ?

Answer (score 6):

in my case, solution was , to restart Mac computer

because i even cannot see my device in Devices menu of xcode

Comment: This too is my only option.

Answer (score 3):

Please Update you Xcode to **6.1**
, The 6.0.1 does't support iOS 8.1.

download Xcode 6.1 from here

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action