# Connecting Iphone 4s to xcode 6.1 , stuck on "iphone is busy: copying symbol files"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, ios8

I've been trying to connect my iphone 4s (running ios 8.1.1) to xcode 6.1 however I cannot go beyond the copying symbol files message. I've tried leaving it connected for as long as 30 mins but it does not go beyond this part.

I've even checked the symbols folder (/Developer/Xcode/ios devicesupport/8.1.1), and it has remained the same size(19kb) no matter how long I leave it, so Im not sure if anything is actually happening.

Does anyone have any ideas on what is wrong?

Here are the things I have tried so far:
-restarting mac & iphone
-chmod the above folder to 777
-delete the above folder

Still nothing works. (Also I am running on mavericks)

[image]

```
*
```

***EDIT: Just got this message after 1 hour:
[image]

Comment: Does your phone have enough available storage to install the app?

Comment: Yes, my iphone has 10GB free (and my mac has 15GB). But I still haven't got to the point where I can install/run my app on the device, its just stuck on the above loading message.

Comment: Upgrading to Yosemite may resolve this issue...

Comment: Is there any thing else I can do other than that, upgrading to yosemite caused problems with other software(unity3d) I currently use on mavericks.

Comment: Just got a new message (above), any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Please check this link, it may provide you some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516267/xcode-6-1-not-detecting-device-iphone-5s-running-ios-8-1

Comment: Still doesn't work. My device shows up as usable, but cant go beyond the above 'copying symbols' step.

Comment: I was able to fix this by running a clean, and disconnecting/reconnecting the phone.